# Deploying ruby on rails app with mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, mina

I have some attachments files in public/uploads/attachments that i want to keep in production server without getting override by mina in the next deployment process ( in case where i change my code )
Is there a way to keep the attachments without getting override ?
Please help

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it like this:

```
set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'log', 'config/secrets.yml','public/uploads']
```

It will then be in the shared folder and not replaced on each deploy